# Is it possible to get a TFS ID to VSTS ID using OpsHub free migration tool?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Using the OpsHub free migration tool to go from TFS to Visual Studio Team Services, is it possible to get an output that says User Story ID 123 is now User Story ID 789?  To give us a mapping to update/reference for use with out support system.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No, unfortunately neither of the OpsHub Migration Utility support this. It is however possible through our commercial tool OIM : http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, OpsHub migration tool does not support this feature.